# Different Property List format on IOS

Tags: ios, format, plist, property-list

I'm facing an issue in using Property List. I've downloaded an example and the PList format is the following:

[image]

and using this code everything works fine:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"content_iPhone" ofType:@"plist"];
contentList = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Now, I'm trying to define a new PList by myself: I've created the new PList file in Xcode, and I've filled it on the User interface (following the previous plist structure), adding three dictionary items:
[image]

In this case, the same code doesn't work and analyzing the xml I see the following:

[image]

It seems that this is a dictionary of items instead of an array, as the first file.
Why? Can you please help me to create a correct property list?

Thanks in advance,
yassa

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's a bug in Xcode 4 — it only lets you make plists where the outer item is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor, change the first `<dict>` to `<array>`, change the last `</dict>` to `</array>`, delete all lines beginning `<key>Item`

Comment: once identified the problem this was obvious, but it's only a workaround and not solves the bug itself.